# Cookies based authentication in asp.net

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, cookies, asp.net-web-api

I am working on a project which is based on asp.net mvc, jquery and web api.
Currently I am setting sessions which are being used to authenticate users.
When an ajax call to web api is made I check if the user is currently logged in then respond him with the data else with an error.

```
 protected override bool IsAuthorized(System.Web.Http.Controllers.HttpActionContext actionContext)
    {
        if (SessionManager.IsUserLoggedIn == false)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

The POCO I'm materializing from login stored procedure contains almost 10 GUID(UserGUID, DeptGUID etc) and int properties.

Now the problem is that I need to completely remove session from application and use cookies to do that authentication process. I've read some solution which propose by using web form authentication I should put all my properties in the cookie (can be encrypted) and send this authentication cookie within request header with every request to the sever. Although I am using GUIDs but some critical flags are in integer form. Will it be wise to put that information out there in client browser?

Also on front end scripts I am making some decisions based upon the values of the properties which are stored in cookies.
[image]

How to ensure that the cookie I am receiving has not been tampered with?
What will be the most efficient and secure way to implement cookie based authentication in my scenario (web api, asp.net mvc )

Comment: The 10GUIDS you speak of must have come from a data source, why can't you query this again? Have you checked out claims based authentication? Essentially each of your GUIDs (UserGUID, DeptGUID etc) can be a claim which forms your security token.

Comment: Yes they are coming from datasource but is querying database every time web api request is received a good idea?
No I hadn't .. Just checked the claims based authentication..going to read more and try it if it fits in the scenario.

Comment: If its a RESTful service, I can't see any issue with requesting the database with every call.

Comment: u can crypted your cookies for security